# Not able to do ssh on a fresh install

Tags: coreos

I've downloaded coreos iso image and installed on a new computer.  Steps I've followed:

Booted from iso with bootable USB
automatically logged in as core user
used sudo su - to become root
As root I ran coreos-install -d /dev/sda -C alpha -c cloud-config.yaml

The installation process downloaded latest build from coreos and written image to my hard disk.  I unplugged the bootable USB.  Now the OS comes up and I can see a login prompt core

I understand there is no password for core with the default install.  The only way is login is SSH from remote m/c.  I configured my ssh key in cloud-config.yaml during the install.  I still can't login.

Any way to debug this?  I'm attaching my cloud-config.yaml here:

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  update:
    reboot-strategy: reboot
  units:
    - name: etcd.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start
ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDEZPCJb6deDxzWk+AxG4fqvU/g5avwoOh9WhfLJXagr1EFcrkuj1zM5NfnPcmjl15RE5nG+DG0s3nlI4NXYa2hBbUKsGsnraSaXfrfO38ymD4AC9N2blQ9jwsUSIIcUQ8HPWwNnhiDWcrY2FTwUdCglvC6PQ1LxhdGrrsuPyb3bDPmXgYQ8qv30AwH0X5QNg1MFwiJT5KgZXR+AETjnZU1ae5K9zScuUymwg2jDFNN4io0qd14RzvSvRSdxw4Ja1oW8Gd5P5Qe/8Rv2SP49Lql1pn03wfEVjp2TqTQwcJA44QEQ1W8e9uuRh27I5g3jrBkYBCWqU417XcnKR6bajBB kesav@C145
hostname: coreos
users:
  - name: kesavkolla
    groups:
      - sudo
      - docker
    primary-group: docker
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDEZPCJb6deDxzWk+AxG4fqvU/g5avwoOh9WhfLJXagr1EFcrkuj1zM5NfnPcmjl15RE5nG+DG0s3nlI4NXYa2hBbUKsGsnraSaXfrfO38ymD4AC9N2blQ9jwsUSIIcUQ8HPWwNnhiDWcrY2FTwUdCglvC6PQ1LxhdGrrsuPyb3bDPmXgYQ8qv30AwH0X5QNg1MFwiJT5KgZXR+AETjnZU1ae5K9zScuUymwg2jDFNN4io0qd14RzvSvRSdxw4Ja1oW8Gd5P5Qe/8Rv2SP49Lql1pn03wfEVjp2TqTQwcJA44QEQ1W8e9uuRh27I5g3jrBkYBCWqU417XcnKR6bajBB kesav@C145
```

Comment: Any suggestions please. I'm kind of stuck. I tried several times installing but not succeeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have several sections nested one level deep when they shouldn't be: `ssh_authorized_keys`, `hostname` and `users`. All of those should be on the same level as `coreos`.

https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/cloudinit-cloud-config/#file-format

Comment: I've adjusted the yaml still no luck.  Any idea on how to debug this?  I've updated my original question with updated config

Answer (score 1):

You can use the autologin option to debug access.

In a nutshell, you need to press any key (space worked for me) at loader prompt, and then enter
    boot_kernel coreos.autologin

See more at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreos-dev/tgg-OAzCOkY